# The largest possible number of intersections between $n$ lines is $n(n-1)/2$

Tags: geometry

Let $C_n$ be the largest possible number of intersection points of a family of $n$ lines in the plane. Prove that $C_n = n(n-1)/2$

(If some lines are parallel, or if three lines intersect at a single point, then the number of intersection points could be less than $C_n$.)

Question for proofs homework, which will be on the upcoming final exam, can somebody please help me with the solution I don't really understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

One idea here is that you can draw the lines in such a way that every pair of lines intersect -- here is where the $C_n=nC2=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ (this is the number of 2-element subsets you can get out of a set of n elements), and they can be made to intersect "optimally" (for your problem/situation). You can do this by making sure that no two lines have the same slop and that no more than 2 lines intersect at a given point.
This means that, out of the n lines, any two can be drawn as to have a point of intersection, so that the number of  intersection points equals the number of pairs of lines. The fact that any two lines can be made to intersect comes from the fact that you can draw them so that no two are parallel, like you said. Then you can just avoid multiple intersections, i.e., more than two lines intersecting at a given point.